# React JSX Styles Without Styles Variable Within Component Scope

Tags: reactjs, sass, jsx

Currently I do:

```
import styles from './RegisterComponent.module.scss
<div className={styles.BackgroundKim}>
```

I find this a bit cumbersome to prefix each style with `style.` as it quite clogs the code and seems like an unnecessary extra text. Can I use the styles I defined in my `component.scss` just in this component without using the variable?

E.g. I have in mind

```
import './RegisterComponent.module.scss'
<div className='BackgroundKim'>
```

But it's not picking up the style.

Comment: Did you select `.BackgroundKim` in that styles file?

Comment: Try it with removing `.module` from scss path i.e. `RegisterComponent.scss` and import this file `import './RegisterComponent.scss'`

Comment: @TahirIqbal that worked. Can you explain me why it treats it so differently?

Comment: @AndiGiga here is an article on sass and its modules integration https://blog.bitsrc.io/how-to-use-sass-and-css-modules-with-create-react-app-83fa8b805e5e

Answer (score 1):

if you console log the styles you will see that :

[image]

look closely
the sass file you imported as styles will looks like a object when you console log it contains the backgorundKim the name you defined in the sass file with styles on the other side you have the random class name that will be put in the jsx element when you inspect it in the dom , at the end theres no way for the jsx element to know what is the random classname without access it from the styles object that you imported as sass file , i hope you understand the point